# PhpStorm Docker & zero-configuration Xdebug

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to set a [zero-configuration debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/zero-configuration-debugging.html) for PhpStorm/Docker/Xdebug.

Xdebug is installed properly (I can see it loaded on `phpinfo()`):

[image]

[image]

My PhpStorm setup for debugging is standard, listening on port `9000`. Here is the xdebug config I'm using:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = docker.for.mac.localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

Off topic: I am also wondering if using `xdebug.idekey` is the same as providing IDE key through Chrome extension?

When I click on PhpStorm to start listening for connections, and set in the configuration to break on first line, I am getting the following:

[image]

Looking at Xdebug logs, it is clear that container connected to client (which is also clear from the fact that I am getting an error when trying to debug).

At this point, I have no manual servers or remote debug configurations set up.

If I define a server and remote debug configuration, and set environment key:

```
environment:
    - PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-server"
```

And then if I click to debug:

[image]

Debugging then works, and no errors appear.
But this is then not a zero-configuration debugging...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* Nothing really. The path mappings (an entry at `PHP | Server`) still needs to be specified, which you do on first incoming debug connection. Zero config is more for debugging web pages .. where Start/Stop debugging is controlled by Browser's Xdebug extension/bookmarklet and there is no need to make Run/Debug Configuration. The `serverName` is when your web server is not fully configured (as IDE needs to know the host name/server name to differentiate between different entries).

Comment: But when I am doing everything without that config part, upon first request I am getting  incoming connection as a window. After that I can see a server created at  `PHP | Server`, though with empty name and host, but mappings provided. It just doesn't work from that point on unless I stop that and do the additional configuration. Are you saying that there is actually no other way than this one?

Comment: As fas as I am aware IDE still needs a server name there to identify what "connection" that is (that's why you do `PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker-server"`). If it's a webpage debug then your webs server is not fully configured (not giving server name to PHP, e.g. `server_name` config for nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). If it's a CLI debug that initiates on remote end (e.g. your `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`) then you also need to provide that server name. For a debug invoked from IDE (Debug button) it should be provided by IDE.

Comment: On related note: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21698, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47573. Maybe worth checking other ones from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23{PHP+Debug}+serverName in case if I'm missing or misunderstanding something here...

Comment: Oh man, setting the `server_name` was what I was looking for! I would've never guessed it. It all works now except when request comes in it maps public folder to `var/www/html/public` and it still doesn't work unless I map the root to `var/www/html`...is there a way to automate that part also? Maybe some other nginx property :D

Comment: Try configuring Deployment entry (and mark it as Default for this project). IDE should use that as a mapping by default (if `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Detect path mappings from deployment configurations` option is enabled -- it's at the very bottom under `Advanced settings` collapsible node. I just do not know if a Deployment makes any sense for a Docker container/ Docker based PHP Interpreter... plus it's a config anyway...

Comment: Yeah, it is checked by default, makes no difference if I have it on or off. Thanks anyways :)